# Syntax error results in blank page

Tags: java, wicket

I am new to wicket and trying to get some things working.
One thing that annoys me a lot is that I get a blank (0 chars of text) page whenever there is a syntax error on a page.

Striped down example:
Test.html

```
header stuff: doctype ... html ... head ... body ...
  <span wicket:id="msgTest" id="message">MSG</span>
footer stuff: /body ... /html
```

Test.java

```
public class Test extends WebPage {
    public Test() {
        add(new Label("msgTest", "Hello, World!"));
    }
}
```

This will output the page as expected.
Now, lets introduce an error:

```
header stuff: doctype ... html ... head ... body ...
  <span wicket:id="msgTest2" id="message">MSG</span>
footer stuff: /body ... /html
```

I changed the label-id to something different then what the source-file expects.
If I run this code I get the already mentioned blank page.
However, for every request to a page with such a syntax error I get an error report in the log-file of around 1000+ lines. This error-report is basically just wicket-generated html of a page which describes the error.
This makes me wonder why wicket isn't displaying the error-stuff instead of the blank page. I'm not very experienced with wicket but to me it somehow looks like wicket is having trouble rendering its own error-page code.

It would be nice to know how one goes about finding syntax-errors with wicket.
Reading through a 1000+ line error-report for a small error like a misplaced character seems a bit tedious.

Thanks in advance for guiding me into the right direction :)

PS:
wicket-version: 1.4.9
stage: development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not confirm that behavior. I went to http://wicket.apache.org/quickstart.html and created a quickstart. Changed the wicket id from 'message' to 'message1' and got a nice descriptive page in jetty:

```
WicketMessage: Unable to find component with id 'message' in [Page class = com.mycompany.HomePage, id = 0, version = 0]. This means that you declared wicket:id=message in your markup, but that you either did not add the component to your page at all, or that the hierarchy does not match.
```

How did you create your project?

Comment: Yepp, found the problem. I have been using apache-ivy to resolve the projects dependencies. This will also fetch wicket-1.4.9-javadoc.jar. The Page which is used to render the error-report is present in both jars, but when the classloader searches for the file it will fetch the one from the javadoc jar. As a result of that rendering the error-page fails and I end uf with the blank page.

I now "blacklisted" the javadoc.jar from beeing copied to the deployment directory, so that the correct error-page is being fetched.

Answer (score 0):

What I like to do is write unit tests with WicketTester to at least verify that things render, and usually also write assertions to check the components.  Something along the lines of

```
@Test
public void testMessageLabel(
    WicketTester tester = new WicketTester();
    tester.startPage(Test.class);
    tester.assertLastRenderedPage(Test.class);
    tester.assertComponent("msgTest", Label.class);
    tester.assertLabel("msgTest", "Hello, World!");
)
```

Then if as in your example the code contains "msgTest" and the html contains "msgTest2" you at least get a test failure instead of seeing it as part of a failing app after deploy.

It's certainly not a complete solution, since this error will make any rendering test for the page fail and the particular failure will just give a long error message in the test result, but at least you don't have to search log files.